# Sumar el resultado de un bucle con el resultado de un IF

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]quisiera saber cómo puedo sumar el resultado de "beta" + resultado de "multiplicar" de tal manera que el total sea= 1+6+2+9+5+1+6+2 = 32.

```
let numeroReversa = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
for (let i = 1; i < numeroReversa.length; i += 2) {
  let multiplicar = parseInt(numeroReversa[i]) * 2;

  if (multiplicar > 9) {
    let alpha = multiplicar.toString();
    let beta = [];
    beta = parseInt(alpha.charAt(0)) + parseInt(alpha.charAt(1))
  }
  let resultado = multiplicar + beta
}
```

Comment: `1+6+2+9+5+1+6+2` -> qué son esos números? de donde salen?...

Comment: Hola @Analiz Anaya Murayari, hay un problema de base con tu ejercicio, en la respuesta que te dieron, corrigieron tus pequeños errores, pero el resultado no coincide con lo que tu  pides, no es porque la respuesta esté equivocada, creo que no hay forma de devolver lo que el ejercicio plantea, o está mal el planteo original, o lo explicaste muy mal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al fin entendí lo que pides:
La idea era: si el número multiplicado por dos, es mayor que nueve, tomamos el valor de la suma de sus componentes y lo sumamos a la variable **resultado**, si no lo es, sumamos a **resultado** el doble de su valor.

```js
let numeroReversa = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let resultado = 0;
for( let i = 1; i < numeroReversa.length; i += 2 ) {
  let multiplicar = numeroReversa[ i ] * 2;
  if( multiplicar > 9 ) {
    let alpha = multiplicar.toString();
    let beta = Number( alpha.charAt(0) ) + Number( alpha.charAt(1) )
    resultado += beta;
  }
  else {
    resultado += multiplicar;
  }
}
console.log( resultado );
```

Para entender los cambios que hice a tu código (y para no ser repetitivo), lee la respuesta de Cris, en la que te explica los sutiles errores que tiene.

Si el array que recibe la función es el original (no el invertido), solo se necesita cambiar las condiciones del **for**, para que itere de atrás hacia adelante.

```
 let numeroOriginal = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
    let resultado = 0;
    for( let i = numeroOriginal.length - 2; i >= 0 ; i -= 2 ) {
      let multiplicar = numeroOriginal[ i ] * 2;
      if( multiplicar > 9 ) {
        let alpha = multiplicar.toString();
        let beta = Number( alpha.charAt(0) ) + Number( alpha.charAt(1) )
        resultado += beta;
      }
      else {
        resultado += multiplicar;
      }
    }
    console.log( resultado );
```

Comment: jeje, lo descubriste :-), +1 por la buena explicación.

Comment: Gracias @Cris223511.dev, me volví loco jaja, y también gracias a ti, estoy siempre aprendiendo de tus respuestas.

Comment: Me alegro :-) saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias :) llevo recién 2 semanas que entré al mundo de la programación y no sé ni cómo plantear mi pregunta, disculpa. Pero es justo lo que estaba buscando Marce :D Gracias!

Comment: @Analiz Anaya Murayari, me alegra haberte ayudado, estamos aquí para eso, y no tienes nada de que disculpate, todos empezamos igual!!!

Answer (score 0):

Por mientras, te corrijo los errores que encontré en tu código. Primero tendrías que declarar la variable `resultado` fuera del todo, para que en el ciclo `for` esta variable sea modificada, siempre mientras entre a la condición o no:

```
let numeroReversa = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let resultado = 0;
for (let i = 1; i < numeroReversa.length; i += 2) {
  //...
}
```

Y dentro de tu condicional `if`, la variable `resultado` estaría de la siguiente manera:

```
resultado += multiplicar + beta;
```

También, el array `beta` nunca lo utilizarías, ya que debajo indicas que `beta` será una suma, y esto no se puede hacer con los arrays:

```
// let beta = [];
let beta = Number(alpha.charAt(0)) + Number(alpha.charAt(1)) // tendría que ser así.
```

Con estos cambios, el resultado de la operación sería el siguiente:

```js
let numeroReversa = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let resultado = 0;
for (let i = 1; i < numeroReversa.length; i += 2) {
  let multiplicar = Number(numeroReversa[i]) * 2;
  if (multiplicar > 9) {
    let alpha = multiplicar.toString();
    let beta = Number(alpha.charAt(0)) + Number(alpha.charAt(1))
    resultado += multiplicar + beta;
  }
}

console.log(resultado)
```